# Tab Activity not showing

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-activity

I am trying to get an Activity to show in a tab but just can't get it to work.
I have checked that the activity shows when on its own but as soon as I try to put it in a tab I get an empty tab.

This is the tab screen and its XML layout file:

```
public class TestTabs extends TabActivity{

private TabHost tabHost;          // The tabhost for all the tabs
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_screen);

    tabHost = getTabHost();

    initTabs();

}



protected void addTab(String tabName, Intent tabIntent){
    TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabName);
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
    tabSpec.setContent(tabIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

}

protected void initTabs() {
    addTab("1",new Intent(this,TestActivity.class));
}

}
```

Layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TabWidget>    
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

This is the "child" activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // The super.onCreate() call will set the general frame also for this Screen:
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

}

Layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

As I said, the child activity shows ok when alone but when I put it in the tab I get the tab without any contents.

I am probably missing something obvious but this is the first time I have done anything with tabs in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change name of method "addTab" because its default method of TabActivity that might be causing this problem.secondly,your code should be like:

```
public class TestTabs extends TabActivity{

    private TabHost tabHost;          // The tabhost for all the tabs
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_screen);

        tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabSpec tabSpec;

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tab1_activity.class);
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab-1").setIndicator("Tab-1",drawable1_obj).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tab2_activity.class);
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab-2").setIndicator("Tab-2",drawable2_obj).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);   

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

    }    
}
```